# Unable to open link with jQuery click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open some relevant links after a button click by user. All these links have to open in a new tab.

I tried using the following code but it does not open the links:

```
$("div.relevant-links").on('click', function() {

  var count = 0;
  var relevant_links = $(this);

  function open_link() {
    if (count < relevant_links.siblings("a.sections").length) {
      relevant_links.siblings("a.sections").eq(count).css({
        background: 'yellowgreen'
      });
      relevant_links.siblings("a.sections").eq(count).click();
      count++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(link_interval);
    }
  }

  open_link();

  var link_interval = setInterval(open_link, 5000);

});
```

All other code works fine because I can see the background color of the link change. However, the `click()` method does not seem to work.

How can I trigger the click on different links? All the links have to open in a new tab. I have set their `target` attributes to `_blank`.

Comment: Try `.eq(count)[0].click()`. Although note that if you have lots of elements in the collection you may be blocked from opening too many tabs at once due to browser security.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Why do I need `[0]` after `.eq(count)`? I thought `.eq(count)` itself would have selected a single element.

Comment: It does, but the `[0]` gets the Element object from the jQuery object allowing you to fake the click event to open the link. jQuery triggered click events do not do this. In fact, if it works, `siblings("a.sections")[0].click()` would be preferable. I'm not sure it will, though

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan :). One last question, using `relevant_links.siblings("a.sections")[count].css()` gave me an error. Is this because `[count]` here was also accessing the element object but the `css()` method is meant for jQuery object?

Comment: That's exactly right. USe `eq(count)` there instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove the interval, if you're going recursive, use setTimeout, if there's even a minor flaw in your code you've got yourself an annoying memory leak.

Second, when you want to open a webpage, new tab or not. You'll need to do it right after a user initiated action like a click. If you're gonna trigger it again after 5 seconds it will get blocked in modern browsers.

Third, you could also retrieve the href of the links and perform a `window.open('your href here', '_blank')` instead of triggering the click event.

Last, don't open a bunch of "relevant" links. You're not making anyone happy with that. Especially not a new one every 5 seconds!